# simple_form inside a block not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a block that generates many forms and somehow all the forms work as expected, except the first one, I am using Rails 3, simple_form and twitter-bootstrap, i have tried removing the twitter-bootstrap part though and it has the same behavior.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="well span4"><h4>Billetes</h4>
<% @paper_bills.each do |pb| %>
    <li class="well well-small">
        <div><%= pb.name %>

        <!-- We show the quantity of paper_bills -->
            <% if @corte.paper_bills != nil %>
                <% @corte.corte_paper_bills.each do |cp| %>
                    <% if cp.paper_bill_id == pb.id %>
                        <p>ID: <%= cp.id %></p>
                        <h6>Cantidad: <%= cp.quantity %></h6>
                        <h5>Suma: <%= cp.suma %></h5>
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div id=<%= "modal_#{pb.id}" %> class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Billetes de <%= pb.name %></h3>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>
                                <%= simple_form_for(@corte_paper_bill, url: corte_paper_bill_path) do |ff| %>
                                    <%= ff.error_notification %>
                                    <%= ff.input :cp_id, 
                                                    input_html: {value: cp.id}, 
                                                    as: :hidden %>
                                    <%= ff.association :corte, 
                                                    input_html: {value: @corte.id},
                                                    as: :hidden %>
                                    <%= ff.association :paper_bill, 
                                                    input_html: {value: pb.id},
                                                    as: :hidden %>
                                    <%= ff.input :quantity %>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                                    <%= ff.button :submit %>
                            <% end %>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
                        <div style="float: right; margin-top: -80px;">
                            <a href=<%= "#modal_#{pb.id}" %> role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal">Actualizar</a>
                        </div>

                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>



        <br />


    </li>
<% end %>
```

Here is the action that works with the forms:

```
def corte_paper_bill
  @corte_paper_bill = CortePaperBill.find(params[:corte_paper_bill][:cp_id])
  attr = params[:corte_paper_bill].except(:cp_id)
  @corte_paper_bill.update_attributes(attr)
  value = @corte_paper_bill.paper_bill.value
  @corte_paper_bill.suma = @corte_paper_bill.quantity * value
  @corte_paper_bill.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to edit_corte_path(@corte_paper_bill.corte_id) }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Here are 2 divs that the block generates:

[image: Divs that the block generates]

When the orange button is clicked it shows this form:

[image]

When I use the form that the first div generates it wont work and it redirects me to a diferent page instead of the one the action should redirect me to.

When i use the form of any other div that the block generated it works as expected.

Can someone help me find why isnt it working?

Thank you in advance

Edit: I have found that when i use the form that is not working properly, the rails server terminal shows this:

```
    Started PUT "/cortes/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-04 10:40:46 -0500
Processing by CortesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"e2k7tN+L0tzQPUyOXJTmTjEnx+2jXzisR/KCa0VSd7A=", "corte_paper_bill"=>{"cp_id"=>"30", "corte_id"=>"8", "paper_bill_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"10"}, "commit"=>"Create Corte paper bill", "id"=>"8"}
  Corte Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "cortes".* FROM "cortes" WHERE "cortes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:5555/cortes/8
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

And when I use the other forms it shows this:

```
Started POST "/corte_paper_bill" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-04 10:49:52 -0500
Processing by CortesController#corte_paper_bill as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"e2k7tN+L0tzQPUyOXJTmTjEnx+2jXzisR/KCa0VSd7A=", "corte_paper_bill"=>{"cp_id"=>"31", "corte_id"=>"8", "paper_bill_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>"10"}, "commit"=>"Create Corte paper bill"}
  CortePaperBill Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "corte_paper_bills".* FROM "corte_paper_bills" WHERE "corte_paper_bills"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "31"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "corte_paper_bills" SET "quantity" = 10, "updated_at" = '2013-05-04 15:49:52.663944' WHERE "corte_paper_bills"."id" = 31
   (16.7ms)  COMMIT
  PaperBill Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "paper_bills".* FROM "paper_bills" WHERE "paper_bills"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE "corte_paper_bills" SET "suma" = 5000.0, "updated_at" = '2013-05-04 15:49:52.692300' WHERE "corte_paper_bills"."id" = 31
   (9.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:5555/cortes/8/edit
Completed 302 Found in 44ms (ActiveRecord: 27.9ms)
```

The "commit" is different, also one uses PUT and the others POST method, dunno why though.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read the very details as the code is too long.

But I think the problem is your `each` method and the `simple_form_for` tag:

```
 <% @corte.corte_paper_bills.each do |cp| %>

<%= simple_form_for(@corte_paper_bill, url: corte_paper_bill_path) do |ff| %>
```

These code together will bring problem because the form code will generate a form with **given certain id**. That's why only one form will work.

The solution is to assign different id in simple form tag

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@corte_paper_bill, url: corte_paper_bill_path, 
   html: {id: "a_custom_id_change_in_each") do |ff| %>
```

Comment: That didnt solve it, but it is weird because then why all the ohter forms work? The block generates like 7 forms, they all work just fine except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was nesting 2 forms, as i didnt need them nested i separated them and the forms worked right.